# how to auto increment string invoice number in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have number `invoice_number` field in `invoice` table.
now i want to add invoice number as string format like `abc/2020/001` where 2020 is current_year and `001` is invoice number as auto increment how can i do this in rails application.

invoice.rb

```
  after_create :set_invoice_number

  def set_invoice_number
    self.update_attribute(:invoice_number, 'ABC/2020/001')
  end
```

in this case i am not able to add auto increment invoice number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would solve your need, as long as the names match:

```rb
  after_create :set_invoice_number

  def set_invoice_number
    self.update_attribute(:invoice_number, 'ABC/' + Time.now.strftime("%Y")
+ '/' + ("%.3i" %self.id))
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems trivial but it's not. The solution involves getting the last invoice from the database, parse its number, and generate the new one. It's also important to keep an eye on concurrency problems that may happen.

```
# Changing to a before_create to avoid going to the database one more time
before_create :set_invoice_number

# You can also use a before_validation to allow you to add validations 
# to check the presence and uniqueness of the new number
# before_validation :set_invoice_number, on: :create

private 

  def set_invoice_number
    self.invoice_number = next_invoice_number
  end

  def next_invoice_number
    # Adding a loop to decrease chances of concurrency problems
    loop do
      number = "#{pattern}/#{current_yer}/#{next_digits}"
      break number unless Invoice.where(invoice_number: number).exists?
    end
  end

  def pattern
    'ABC'
  end

  def current_year
    Time.now.strftime('%Y')
  end

  # This solution to get the next digit will keep increasing the digits even if the yer changes. 
  # It will need some improvements if you want to restart the count
  def next_digits
    last_digits = Invoice.last.invoice_number.split('/').to_i
    "%.3i" %(last_digits + 1)
  end
end
```